# The TransportManager failed to listen on the supplied URI using the NetTcpPortSharing service: the service failed to listen

Tags: wcf-binding

When I try to start the service I am receiving this exception.

System.ServiceModel.AddressAlreadyInUseException: The TransportManager failed to listen on the supplied URI using the NetTcpPortSharing service: the service failed to listen

Any suggestion or help is apricated.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this website to troubleshoot: https://mytechref.wordpress.com/2009/12/08/the-transportmanager-failed-to-listen-on-the-supplied-uri-using-the-nettcpportsharing-service/

and also [How to: Enable the Net.TCP Port Sharing Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-enable-the-net-tcp-port-sharing-service?redirectedfrom=MSDN)